# iOS10 failed to play the sound of Push Notifications when I cover to install my app by XCode 8

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ios10, xcode8

I am getting this error that failed to play the sound which is customed on iOS 10 . 
It can not play when I cover to install my app...
It can play when I remove the old app and then install the new app.

It is running okay before iOS10

How can I solve that? 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Also in the same situation any help would be appreciated as it is affecting my TestFlight build

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, will be solved in iOS 10.1

Comment: But it solved by Apple without reinstall my app on user's iPhone?

Comment: The app must be built with Xcode 8.1, that is with 10.1 SDK. So you got to push an update.